# 1053 Error when starting ASP.NET Core 6.0.22 Service

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm getting this 1053 error when I try to start the service:

> Windows could not start the "MyService" service on Local Computer.
> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

I think I understand the error, but I don't know how to fix it. All solutions I found to similar problems did not work (or I implemented them wrong). Maybe this is trivial and a duplicate but I'm new to this framework and don't know what I'm doing/have to look for. So explanations in the answers would help me a lot.

The service consists of a worker, that executes a method every 60 seconds, as well as an API endpoint that triggers the method every time it is called. When I run the service from Visual Studio or from the `.exe` file, everything works, so I assume it has to do something with the `Program.cs`.

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        
        builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
        builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();                        
        builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

        var app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseAuthorization();
        app.MapControllers();
        app.Run();
    }
```

Worker:

```
 public class Worker : BackgroundService

 protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
 {
     // Classes for Oracle db and SQL db connections are created here
     while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
     {
         ReadCycle();
         await Task.Delay(delaytime * 60 * 1000, stoppingToken);
     }
 }

 public void ReadCycle()
 {
     try
     {
         //do stuff
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        //log stuff
     }
 }
```

The API controller:

```
public class Controller : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public Controller(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<bool>> Post([FromBody]Model model)
    {
        var worker = serviceProvider.GetServices<IHostedService>()
                                    .OfType<Worker>()
                                    .FirstOrDefault();
        if (worker != null)
        {
            worker.ReadCycle();
            return CreatedAtAction("POST", true);
        }

        return CreatedAtAction("POST", false);                
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: To be clear, you want to run your ASP.NET Core web application as a Windows service rather than hosted behind a reverse proxy like IIS?

Comment: All i want is a method that is executed every 60 seconds and that is executeable by an API call. The API part of the solution was decided on 3 months after the 60 seconds part, so i tried to avoid complete redevelopment of the application hence the solution

Comment: You don't need it to be a Windows service for that. The background process (`Worker`) will run within the IIS worker process that hosts the API.

Comment: I would move `ReadCycle` out of `Worker`, though. It doesn't belong to either of the things that need to call it, and given that you have it as an instance method, the API controller would have to create an instance of `Worker` (so, not the same instance that's running as a background service) to call it and that's probably not what you want.

Comment: so just remove the >builder.Services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); ?

Comment: No, don't remove that. You need that to have it do that action every 60 seconds.  I'm saying don't run it as a Windows service. Run it as you would any API, hosted in IIS.

Comment: How else would i run it? Sorry if I sound stupid to you, this is just completely new for me

Answer (score 0):

Could you try below sample code:

Program.cs:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); // Assumes existence of Startup.cs for configurations
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>(); // Registers your Worker as a hosted service
        });
```

Worker.cs

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly IMethodRunner _methodRunner;

    public Worker(IMethodRunner methodRunner)
    {
        _methodRunner = methodRunner;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await _methodRunner.RunMethodAsync();
            await Task.Delay(60000, stoppingToken); 
        }
    }
}
```

MethodRunner.cs:

```
public interface IMethodRunner
{
    Task RunMethodAsync();
}

public class MethodRunner : IMethodRunner
{
    public async Task RunMethodAsync()
    {
        // Your code to run every 60 seconds or on-demand here
    }
}
```

Controller.cs:

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMethodRunner _methodRunner;

    public MyController(IMethodRunner methodRunner)
    {
        _methodRunner = methodRunner;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Post()
    {
        await _methodRunner.RunMethodAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllers();
        
        services.AddScoped<IMethodRunner, MethodRunner>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        .....
    .......
    }
}
```